# Recover from AMDGPU-PRO install

Tags: boot, drivers, amdgpu

I have been running Xubuntu 16.04 without any errors on just the generic drivers that come installed by default. I decided I wanted to play some video games so I installed the AMDGPU-PRO drivers by following the directions here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx

```
cd /tmp
tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro-17.10-414273.tar.xz
cd amdgpu-pro-17.10-414273
./amdgpu-pro-install -y
```

now when I boot my computer, I see my motherboard startup screen and can access the bios, but if I try and boot the SSD my install is on, I just get a black screen it doesn't appear to be outputting a video signal. I've tried 3 monitors all with the same result, I am not too worried about getting AMDGPU-PRO drivers to work, just with getting my system bootable again. So my quesiton is how can I boot into a state that I can uninstall the drivers?

I've tried SSHing into my desktop from my laptop, but my desktop isn't responding to that.

For anyone looking into this currently, I never solved for 16.04, but a Radeon R9 390 with AMDGPU-PRO is working great on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 8):

Ran into this question while trying to solve the same problem, I solved it just by uninstalling amd driver.

- Enter ubuntu Recovery mode while booting in.
- Enable networking and mount file system using the recovery options.
- Now "Drop to the root shell prompt".
- Use amdgpu-pro-uninstall command to uninstall.

"exit" and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling everything so I can't test this, but that definitely looks like what the right course of action would've been except I couldn't boot into grub to access recovery mode

Comment: Indeed the right approach! Got it removed with this method!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue it is because of the modification to the **initrd** file in /boot folder. You can recover by reverting to the old **initrd** file stored in /boot as **initrd.dkms.old**. I didn't know how to do that, so I just reinstalled the OS.

Also, the amd install guide said that there is a **amdgpu-pro-uninstall** script in the extracted folder but there isn't.

Update if you find a way to reverting to the old **initrd** or another way to fix the problem apart from re-installation.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just reinstalling and am going to avoid amdgpu drivers a bit longer

Comment: This worked for me! Saved me hours of work not having to re-install. Thanks :)

Comment: I found the `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` script was linked as `/usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall` into `/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/` as part of the installation procedure. Their docs have not been updated to describe that departure from their instructions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` script for newer installs it can probably be found in a different directory (as mentioned in the comments), try

```
/usr/bin/amdgpu-uninstall
/usr/bin/amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an `--uninstall` option in `amdgpu-pro-install.sh`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the amdgpu-pro-uninstall sh file is missing at least in my case
However in the amdgpu-install.sh file there is an uninstall function called by dryrun

```
if [[ "${OPTIONS[*]}" =~ "dryrun" ]]; then
    echo PACKAGES: ${PACKAGES[*]}
    amdgpu_pro_uninstall
    return 0
fi
```

Try /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/amdgpu-install --dryrun